# Alerts on SharePoint Home Page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-on-prem, alert

I was wondering if it is possible to setup Alerts on a new subsite (home page) that was created? If so, can you setup the Alerts to send info on lists\libraries (web parts) that are displayed on it?

If not, are the alerts on the new subsite (home page) only used to update on page edits, new web parts added, etc.?

Reason I ask is because when I try to setup alerts on the new subsite (home page), the entire ribbon is greyed out. But I have full control on it.

I am able to setup alerts though, but within the list and libraries that exist in the site.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to add alerts on site page changes or list/library changes

Comment: I am trying to add an alert to the site page but its greyed out as you see above. I have full control and still unable to use the alert option. I tested this on another site page and the alert option was available.

Comment: Do you have full control permissions on this particular site page? Check if permissions inheritance is broken for this site page. I am able to set the alerts on default home page created when site is created (check my answer below).

Comment: Inheritance is broken. Could this be the reason why?

Comment: Yes, check your permissions for this particular page. If you have enough permissions, you should be able to see the alerts option.

Answer (score 0):

I can add alerts on site page without any problem. I am trying this in normal page mode & not edit mode.

[image]

You can only send alerts based on following changes to the site page:

[image]

You cannot send page changes information to list/library web parts on page using alerts functionality.